# Color Change to Mouse effect in JavaFX

Tags: events, colors, mouse, javafx

I want to change this code so when I click on the ball, it turns red. Can anyone help me? I'm new to java:
http://download.oracle.com/javafx/1.3/tutorials/ui/syntax/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;


var circle: Circle;
Stage {
    title: "Declaring Is Easy!"
    scene: Scene {
        width: 300
        height: 250
        content: [
            circle = Circle {
                centerX: 150  centerY: 120 radius: 80
                fill: Color.MAROON
                stroke: Color.INDIANRED
                strokeWidth: 10.0

            }, //Circle
            Rectangle {
                x: 25, y: 80 width: 250, height: 80
                arcWidth: 20 arcHeight: 20
                fill: Color.web("#6699ff")
                stroke: Color.web("#003399")
            strokeWidth: 5.0
                onMouseClicked:function(e: MouseEvent)
                {
                 if(circle.fill == Color.MAROON)
                    circle.fill = Color.GREEN
                 else
                    circle.fill = Color.MAROON
                }

            } //Rectangle
        ] //Content
    } //Scene
} //Stage
```

Two changes here: 
1) Extract Circle in a variable (circle), so that it can be used later.
2) Add a mouse clicked event to the rectangle, to flip colors.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to change the word circle into rectangle right here

```
if(**circle**.fill == Color.MAROON)
                    **circle**.fill = Color.GREEN
                 else
                    **circle**.fill = Color.MAROON
                }

if(**rectangle**.fill == Color.MAROON)
                    **rectangle**.fill = Color.GREEN
                 else
                    **rectangle**.fill = Color.MAROON
                }
```

and put in this sentence var rectangle : Rectangle; just like `var circle: Circle;`